# T-SQL query to show table definition?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is a query that will show me the full definition, including indexes and keys for a SQL Server table?  I want a pure query - and know that SQL Studio can give this to me, but I am often on "wild" computers that have only the most bare-bones apps and I have no rights to install studio.  But SQLCMD is always an option.

UPDATE:  I have tried sp_help, but is just yields one record which shows Name, Owner, Type and Created_Datetime.  Is there something else I am missing with sp_help?

Here is what I call:

sp_help airports

Note that I really do want the DDL that defines the table.

Comment: What you're missing with `sp_help` is that it returns multiple result sets. You're describing the columns returned by the first result set.

Comment: Good question. Coming from MySQL, the solutions fall too short, for one can't see columns, indexes, foreign keys, constraint names all in one place. This is severe when you have many databases/tables in your object explorer. Hope Microsoft addresses this in the future. I haven't used any productivity tools but [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/) looks promising.

Comment: @Microsoft please add DESC TABLE like MySQL.  Easy.  Simple. Done.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

There is no easy way to return the DDL. However you can get most of the details from [Information Schema Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) and [System Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177862.aspx).

```
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
       , IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Customers'

SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Customers'

SELECT name, type_desc, is_unique, is_primary_key
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Customers')
```

Comment: Thank  you.  I was beginning to suspect that the only way to get this would be to query into a number of separate tables, and that it is what SQL Studio does when you tell it to "generate DDL".  I'ma but surprised there is no general SP that will do it for you.

Comment: It is. If you want only the column info, you can execute `sp_columns` as I mentioned in my answer. If you want info about FKs run `sp_fkeys`. If you want to know indexes, execute `sp_statistics`.

Answer (score 84):

Have you tried sp_help?

```
sp_help 'TableName'
```

Comment: This shows structure, constraints, contraint types etc. Just one thing to note: you must write full name of the datatable. Schema.TableName. Otherwise, it completely solves the problem and gives all info about table.

Comment: Does not return the DDL of the table, even with the full path written.

Answer (score 31):

Visit http://www.stormrage.com/SQLStuff/sp_GetDDL_Latest.txt.

You will find the code of `sp_getddl` procedure for SQL Server.
The purpose of the procedure is script any table, temp table or object.

USAGE:

```
exec sp_GetDDL GMACT
```

or

```
exec sp_GetDDL 'bob.example'
```

or

```
exec sp_GetDDL '[schemaname].[tablename]'
```

or

```
exec sp_GetDDL #temp
```

I tested it on SQL Server 2012, and it does an excellent job.

I'm not the author of the procedure.  Any improvement you make to it send to Lowell Izaguirre (scripts@stormrage.com).

Comment: Thank you for this script and sharing! I would ask, do you have a post where we can discuss about this script?

Comment: Excellent! MSFT must have such function inside Management Studio

Comment: This did not  work for me, it gives error message as,                                                   
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 74
Could not find stored procedure 'sp_GetDDL'.

Comment: @yuvraj, this is not a built-in procedure. You'll have to define it yourself using the code linked in the answer.

Answer (score 20):

The easiest and quickest way I can think of would be to use [sp_help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335.aspx)

`sp_help 'TableName'`

Answer (score 19):

Since SQL 2012 you can run the following statement:

```
Exec sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql= N'Select * from <yourtable>'
```

If you enter a complex select statement (joins, subselects, etc), it will give you the definition of the result set. This is very handy, if you need to create a new table (or temp table) and you don't want to check every single field definition manually.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql

Answer (score 18):

Use this little Windows command-line app that gets the `CREATE TABLE` script (with constraints) for any table. I've written it in C#. Just compile it and carry it on a memory stick. Perhaps someone can port it to Powershell.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
namespace ViewSource
{
    public class ViewSource
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 6)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("Syntax: ViewSource.exe <server>" +
                     " <user> <password> <database> <schema> <table>");
            }

            Script(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5]);
        }
        private static void Script(string server, string user,
            string password, string database, string schema, string table)
        {
            new Server(new ServerConnection(server, user, password))
                .Databases[database]
                .Tables[table, schema]
                .Script(new ScriptingOptions { SchemaQualify = true,
                                               DriAll = true })
                .Cast<string>()
                .Select(s => s + "\n" + "GO")
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't T-SQL though

Comment: I wonder what you'd see if you used SQL Profiler to capture the commands this kicked off. :->

Comment: Just wanted to add that this won't script out any CDC tables :( as it's currently not supported in SMO.

Comment: I added an answer with a PowerShell port. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 11):

```
sp_help 'YourTableName'
```

Answer (score 7):

This will return columns, datatypes, and indexes defined on the table:

```
--List all tables in DB
select * from sysobjects where xtype = 'U'

--Table Definition
sp_help TableName
```

This will return triggers defined on the table:

```
--Triggers in SQL Table
select * from sys.triggers where parent_id = object_id(N'SQLTableName')
```

Answer (score 7):

I know it's an old question, but exactly what I was looking for. Because I want to batch script some tables, I rewrote the C# code from Anthony Faull for PowerShell.

This one is uses Integrated Security:

```
Import-Module sqlps

$serverInstance = "<server>"
$database = "<database>"
$table = "<table>"
$schema = "<schema>"

$options = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions
$options.DriAll = $true
$options.SchemaQualify = $true

$connection = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection `
    -ArgumentList $serverInstance
$server = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server `
    -ArgumentList $connection

$server.Databases.Item($database).Tables.Item($table, $schema).Script($options) `
    | ForEach-Object -Process { $_ + "`nGO"}
```

And here with username and password:

```
Import-Module sqlps

$serverInstance = "<server>"
$user = "<user>"
$password = "<pasword>"
$database = "<database>"
$table = "<table>"
$schema = "<schema>"

$options = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions
$options.DriAll = $true
$options.SchemaQualify = $true

$connection = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection `
    -ArgumentList $serverInstance
$connection.LoginSecure = $false
$connection.Login = $user
$connection.Password = $password
$server = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server `
    -ArgumentList $connection

$server.Databases.Item($database).Tables.Item($table, $schema).Script($options) `
    | ForEach-Object -Process { $_ + "`nGO"}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply type the table name and select it and press ATL + F1

Say your table name is `Customer` then open a *new query window*, type and select the table name and press ALT + F1

It will show the complete definition of table.

Comment: Good one )) But for me, it shows data for the whole database. I've tried new query windows with just table name in it and it doesn't work - it always shows everything. Otherwise, nice tip :)

Comment: I used it with 2008 and 2012, not sure about the older versions, and it always works for me, Just the table name and ALT + F1, if want to use the schema then 'schema.table'.

Comment: It is the shortcut of sp_help 'schema.tablename'

Comment: Worked when I selected \ highlighted the table name.  Showed entire database if there was anything else in the query window.

Comment: That just gets me a message about accessibility and screen-readers.

Answer (score 4):

A variation of @Anthony Faull's answer for those using LINQPad:

```
new Server(new ServerConnection(this.Connection.DataSource))
    .Databases[this.Connection.Database]
    .Tables["<table>", "dbo"]
    ?.Script(new ScriptingOptions {
        SchemaQualify = true,
        DriAll = true,
    })
```

You'll need to reference 2 assemblies:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

And add namespace references as mentioned in Anthony's snippet.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
       , IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEES'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the sp_help stored procedure.

sp_help <>

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to execute [sp_columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176077.aspx) procedure.

```
EXEC sys.sp_columns @TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'
```

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to Barry's answer. The sp_help can also be used by itself to iterate all of the objects in a particular database. You also have sp_helptext for your arsenal, which scripts out programmatic elements, like stored procedures.

Answer (score 2):

General table definition is shown using stored procedure `sp_help`, as said before:

> sp_help 'table_name_in_current_db_context'

When using tables of multiple contexts is useful to prefix the command above with the desired context, instead of changing them with `use db_xyz`:

> DB_Products..sp_help 'MyTable' -- for definition of MyTable in DB_Products

And it works with temp tables also:

> tempdb..sp_help '#TempTable' -- for definition of #TempTable in current context.

Answer (score -2):

There is an easy way to get DDL scripts for any database object.

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Connect to the source database server.
3. Expand the databases tree.
4. Right-click on the database with the tables to export.
5. In the sub-menu, expand "Tasks".
6. In the sub-menu, choose "Generate Scripts..."
7. Use the wizard to choose the objects to export.
8. For the scripting options, choose 1 script per object.

This will export a file for every table, view, stored proc, user, role, or schema you chose. Take that to the destination computer.

Comment: The question explicitly asks how to without using management studio