# Query to find a table definition

Tags: sql, t-sql

I just created a table in tsql but now I want to be able to get the definition of that table, like the column name, whether its int or nvarchar or whatever parameter it is, whether it's null, etc. What's the tsql query for that?

Comment: just `sp_help [YourTableName]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL query to show table definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215459/t-sql-query-to-show-table-definition)

Answer (score 0):

You can query the schema for this, like so:

```
SELECT 
   ORDINAL_POSITION,
   DATA_TYPE,
   CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
   IS_NULLABLE,
   COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM   
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE   
   TABLE_NAME = 'Product' 
ORDER BY 
   ORDINAL_POSITION ASC;
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick response. I tried that, the query runs successfully, but I get no data.

Comment: The query is working for me, but I'm using postgres. Regardless, this is in the ANSI standard, so it should work on any framework. Not sure what the problem is, sorry

Comment: The query DOES work, it just shows nothing under all of those columns.

Comment: Are you certain you're using the correct table name? Maybe try querying all the columns, by removing the where clause

Comment: Yup, querying the correct table name. I'm just trying to get the table info of one table, I did not know it was going to be this complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ColumnName  = C.Name
,   ColumnSeq   = C.column_id
,   DataType    = T.name
,   MaxLength   = C.max_length
,   Percision   = C.precision
,   Scale       = c.scale
,   IsNullable  = C.Is_nullable
,   IsIdentiy   = C.Is_identity
,   Colation    = c.collation_name
FROM sys.Columns C
JOIN sys.Types T ON T.System_Type_id = C.System_Type_id
where c.object_id = object_id('dbo.product')
order by c.column_id
```