# Retrieving the sql statement that makes out a view, sp or function, MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, view

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to (from C#) retrieve the SQL statement that created a specific View, Stored Procedure, Function etc. on a MSSQL server?

UPDATE:

The suggestion by R. Richards, using "sp_helptext" was what I was looking for. I wasn't aware of this procedure, thanks :)

Comment: take a look here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215459/t-sql-query-to-show-table-definition) and here (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95262/get-object-script-in-sql-server-via-t-sql)

Comment: You could consider using [SMO Scripter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/scripting). Or, check out [sp_helptext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql).

Comment: what is the scenerio like ?

Comment: The suggestion by R. Richards, using "sp_helptext" was what I was looking for. I wasn't aware of this procedure, thanks :)