# How to parameterize SELECT and FROM tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I need to extract tables from one SQL database into another SQL database. There are about 100+ tables.
I would like to create a parameterized script for the SELECT and FROM tables so that the one script can be used to loop through all the tables.

Is this possible? I would really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Table definitions and/or table data?

Comment: @jarlh preferably with the table definitions and table data.

Comment: Have you considered using Import/Export feature in SSMS? You also could export your whole database schema using it.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I have, but would like to create a generic script that may be re-purposed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL query to show table definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215459/t-sql-query-to-show-table-definition)

Comment: Hi @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh unfortunately not. Thank you though.